# How to get a new view controller instead of parent view for a 1st tab in tabbar view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I struck in a problem with using tab bar controller to my view controller.

Here is my problem

I have a view controller for that i embedded a tab bar controller and i have added four tabs for it and three views are created for the other three tabs, here is my Exact problem. i don't want my 1st tab bar controller select default if i click on my 1st tab i want to show the other view it should not display my parent view where i am showing all the tabs in a parent view.

Please give me some solution how to overcome this. hope my question is clear with details.

Comment: Once more - with punctuation?  Maybe it's the hour, but I am finding your question hard to understand.

Comment: see i embedded a tabbar control to view control 1st tab will be the view control which i embed right that i don't want thats i want new for first tab like other tabs will get new view right in my parent view i want to show all the tabs if click on tabs i want new view for all the tabs even for 1st tab also

Comment: hi chrisco u got my question?

Comment: No - no I did not.  I can barely (it at all) understand what you are saying, as your post is devoid of punctuation and reads as one long sentence without context.  I wish you good luck.

Comment: chris please go through this url u will findout my problem  
postimg.org/image/m0erf5u5x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I am able understand your problem. Without posting code sometime its very difficult to identify exact problem.

I am sharing a code with you , assume that App launch a single view controller as "Login View Controller" which is follow by "Dashboard View Controller". Now you want to show TabBar after user login with four different tabs.

Please called below method "setUpTabBar" within Dashboard View Controller ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void)setUpTabBar
{

       UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc1.title = @"Tab1";
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UINavigationController *nav1 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
    nav1 =[self setTrasparentNav:nav1];

    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc2.title = @"Tab2";
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UINavigationController *nav2 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
    nav2 =[self setTrasparentNav:nav2];


    UIViewController *vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc3.title = @"Tab3";
    vc3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     UINavigationController *nav3 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];
       nav3 =[self setTrasparentNav:nav3];

    UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    tabBar.viewControllers = @[nav1,nav2,nav3];
    tabBar.selectedIndex   = 0;
    tabBar.view.frame = self.view.bounds;


    [tabBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];
    [self addChildViewController:tabBar];
    [tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

You can change default selected tab bar using `tabBar.selectedIndex   = 0`;

Hope this will help you.

Update (As requested by questionnaire):-

```
UIView *viewBottom=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height- 60.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 60.0)];
    viewBottom.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];


    UIButton *btnAdd =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    btnAdd.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 60.0, 40.0);

    [viewBottom addSubview:btnAdd];

    [self.view addSubview:viewBottom];
```

Comment: Thank you thank you very much for your help if get any doubts how do i contact you?? pls give me any  mode i am fresher struggling hard so

Comment: dude it is not taking for table view controller it is taking it as a prototype cell and view is not aliging at the bottom. at my asset page i used tabelview controller

Comment: Ok Then either you have tried with code or take UiViewController then add UItableViewcontroler and resize it according to your need. then you can add Uiview at botton

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying from code, first see how to make uitabbarcontroller in code: [How to programmatically add a UITabBarController & UINavigationController in AppDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132532/how-do-you-programmatically-add-a-uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationcontroller-in)

Comment: thanks for the reply i don't want to do that from code because any time my ui may change so i want to keep it simple through interface builder