# How can we add Navigation Bottom bar programmatically?

Tags: ios

Navigation BottomBar add programmatically. Which includes 4 button is shown in the Figure. Now I am using just a UIView and added 4 buttons to it. It doesn't help for me.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a `UITabBar`.

Comment: actually i am using one library MWPhotoBrowser in that i want to add this bottom like this.. Actually i search lot of things at last i decided to question in stack.... Can u help me.. @dasdom

Comment: I already did. Add an instance of `UITabBar` to the view.

Comment: @dasdom u already done with this library great... Ok i added uitabbar to my view

Comment: @sreezzz :- You should use UITabBarController. In order to add this programatically refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132532/how-do-you-programmatically-add-a-uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationcontroller-in