# Want TabBar hidden in few controllers of the page view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a tab bar controller programatically in appdelegate.m like in several [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132532/how-do-you-programmatically-add-a-uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationcontroller-in) online.
I am setting the view controllers of the tab bar controller like this -

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1, navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,navigationController5];
```

The issue i am not being able to solve is that navigationController1 is itself a pageViewController and it is parent to 3 view controllers.
I want to hide the tab bar for 2 of these 3 view controllers but am unable to do so.

Explaining by use of a gif - https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0wA3.jpg - so on the left and right swipes in the pageview controller i would like to hide the tab bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you want to have functionality like Instagram, you should change your design approach. Because Tab bar is moving with slide, hence it looks like a child of Page View Controller.

Instead of taking Page View Controller inside Tab Bar Controller, take Tab bar Controller inside the Page View Controller.

So it will look like this:

Page View Controller [View Controller 1, Tab bar Controller[five Nav Controllers], View Controller 3].

I would love to see you implement it.

Comment: this is a good idea, will try in the evening and will get back to you.

Comment: Good Job!! Bravo!

Comment: @Bista if i want to disable scroll to another VC in `PageViewController` in a few `TabBarController`, how can i handle it? for example user can scroll from `TabBarController[0]` to `ViewController3`, but cant do this from `TabBarController[1]`

Answer (score 1):

To hide Tabbar in a ViewController, use the following code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

   }
```

To unhide Tabbar in a ViewController, use the following code:

```
 self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: hi , i tried this and it did hide the tabbar however, the tabbar remained hidden for other viewcontrollers also  - http://imgur.com/kCYG9y4

Comment: For others, use: self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;

Comment: @SathiReddy i tried that but tab bar remains gray color as shown in http://imgur.com/kCYG9y4

Comment: @Mr.UB no not solved, im basically looking for the effect in the real instagram app.

Comment: I think they are putting 3 ViewControllers in one Page View Controller.
Camera,TabBar and Direct. Because the Tab  bar is sliding with Page Slide.

Comment: Please try this (for hiding) :  self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;                                 For unhiding: self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;