# How to set rootview in tabbar controller and show tabbar in each view controller in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar as UITabBar


    let tabBarItem0 = tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items![1] as! UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem2 = tabBar.items![2] as! UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem3 = tabBar.items![3] as! UITabBarItem

            tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

    tabBarItem0.title = "Home"
    tabBarItem1.title = "Search"
    tabBarItem2.title = "User"
```

I am new to swift. I have configured the tab bar controller in appdelegate.Now I need to set the rootview controller here and I need to show the tabbar in all my viewcontrollers that I declare.

Comment: Why don't you use Storyboard?

Comment: @Amanpreet. I have already started it using xib. Can you please help?

Comment: Better is to use Storyboard. I will give you a scenario how to make it.

Comment: @Amanpreet. Please try to understand. I need to make it work in xib. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Ok. Check this. It will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132532/how-to-programmatically-add-a-uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationcontroller-in-app

Answer (score 4):

This will help you. Try to set navigation inside of tab bar controller. Give tab bar item to navigation controller. Like:

[image]

Output is:

[image]

When you press button:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create tabbarcontroller like below, using Xib

```
    //MARK: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

        let tabViewController1 = FirstTabViewController(nibName: "FirstTabViewController", bundle: nil)
        let tabViewController2 = SecondViewController(nibName:"SecondViewController", bundle: nil)

        tabViewController1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home_icon"),tag: 1)
        tabViewController2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search",image:UIImage(named: "search_icon") ,tag:2)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [tabViewController1,tabViewController2] 

        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to achieve something like this :

`UITabBarController` --> for each tab there will be a `navigation controller` whose Root will be a `VC` having tab bar

So I would suggest you to directly use `UITabBarControllers` for your each root of `navigation controller`.

That means your root will be `UITabBarController`, then for each `tab` there will be `UINavigationController` whose first `view controller` will be again a `UITabBarController`.

For more understanding see below figure. It's only showing flow for one tab of `UITabBarController`. Repeat the same for all your other `tabs`.

[image]